# OpenCV with Python - Trying to overlay an image over the eyes on a webcam feed

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Total newbie to computer vision. I'm trying to modify the code given [here](http://sublimerobots.com/2015/02/dancing-mustaches/) to detect and overlay an image (png) of sunglasses over the eyes.

While running the program, the webcam opens and the eyes are detected, but the image isn't visible. The terminal output shows no error (It says 'init done' and 'opengl support available'). What is it that I'm doing wrong?
Here's my code -

```
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

# Load the overlay image: glasses.png
imgGlasses = cv2.imread('1.png')

print imgGlasses is None

# Create the mask for the glasses
imgGlassesGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgGlasses, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imgGlassesGray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
#orig_mask = imgGlasses[:,:,3]

# Create the inverted mask for the glasses
orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)

# Convert glasses image to BGR
# and save the original image size (used later when re-sizing the image)
imgGlasses = imgGlasses[:,:,0:3]
origGlassesHeight, origGlassesWidth = imgGlasses.shape[:2]

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)

        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            glassesWidth = 3*ew
            glassesHeight = glassesWidth * origGlassesHeight / origGlassesWidth

            # Center the glasses on the bottom of the nose
            x1 = ex - (glassesWidth/4)
            x2 = ex + ew + (glassesWidth/4)
            y1 = ey + eh - (glassesHeight/2)
            y2 = ey + eh + (glassesHeight/2)

                # Check for clipping
            if x1 < 0:
                x1 = 0
            if y1 < 0:
                y1 = 0
            if x2 > w:
                x2 = w
            if y2 > h:
                y2 = h

            # Re-calculate the width and height of the glasses image
            glassesWidth = x2 - x1
            glassesHeight = y2 - y1

            # Re-size the original image and the masks to the glasses sizes
            # calcualted above
            glasses = cv2.resize(imgGlasses, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            # take ROI for glasses from background equal to size of glasses image
            roi = roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2]

            # roi_bg contains the original image only where the glasses is not
            # in the region that is the size of the glasses.
            roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

            # roi_fg contains the image of the glasses only where the glasses is
            roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(glasses,glasses,mask = mask)

            # join the roi_bg and roi_fg
            dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)

            # place the joined image, saved to dst back over the original image
            roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2] = dst

            break

    # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code posted there are indentation problems such as:

```
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
```

should be:

```
for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
    cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
```

The reason why the code is failing to show the visualization is that it is too far inside the for loops. This requires too many changes in the visualization over a small period of time. Specifically you have:

```
while True:
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

Proposed solution:

1. Remove extra tabs in front of `cv2.imshow`
2. Add `cv2.waitKey()`, which will ask for a confirmation every time the image changes.

Here is one possible solution:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import cv2
from itertools import count

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

# Load the overlay image: glasses.png
imgGlasses = cv2.imread('eye.png')

#Check if the files opened
if  imgGlasses is None :
    exit("Could not open the image")
if  face_cascade.empty() :
    exit("Missing: haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
if  eye_cascade.empty() :
    exit("Missing: haarcascade_eye.xml")


# Create the mask for the glasses
imgGlassesGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgGlasses, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imgGlassesGray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

#orig_mask = imgGlasses[:,:,3]

# Create the inverted mask for the glasses
orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)

# Convert glasses image to BGR
# and save the original image size (used later when re-sizing the image)
imgGlasses = imgGlasses[:,:,0:3]
origGlassesHeight, origGlassesWidth = imgGlasses.shape[:2]

#cv2.imshow('Video', imgGlasses)
#cv2.waitKey()


video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not video_capture.isOpened() :
    exit('The Camera is not opened')


counter = count(1)

while True:
    print "Iteration %d" % counter.next()
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)

        #cv2.imshow('Video', roi_gray)
        #cv2.waitKey()

        #print 'X:%i, Y:%i, W:%i, H:%i' % (x, y, w, h)
        for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
            print 'EX:%i, EY:%i, EW:%i, EH:%i' % (ex, ey, ew, eh)

        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            glassesWidth = 3*ew
            glassesHeight = glassesWidth * origGlassesHeight / origGlassesWidth

            # Center the glasses on the bottom of the nose
            x1 = ex - (glassesWidth/4)
            x2 = ex + ew + (glassesWidth/4)
            y1 = ey + eh - (glassesHeight/2)
            y2 = ey + eh + (glassesHeight/2)

                # Check for clipping
            if x1 < 0:
                x1 = 0
            if y1 < 0:
                y1 = 0
            if x2 > w:
                x2 = w
            if y2 > h:
                y2 = h

            # Re-calculate the width and height of the glasses image
            glassesWidth = x2 - x1
            glassesHeight = y2 - y1

            # Re-size the original image and the masks to the glasses sizes
            # calcualted above
            glasses = cv2.resize(imgGlasses, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

            # take ROI for glasses from background equal to size of glasses image
            roi = roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2]

            # roi_bg contains the original image only where the glasses is not
            # in the region that is the size of the glasses.
            roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)

            # roi_fg contains the image of the glasses only where the glasses is
            roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(glasses,glasses,mask = mask)

            # join the roi_bg and roi_fg
            dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)

            # place the joined image, saved to dst back over the original image
            roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2] = dst
    #break
    #Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    cv2.waitKey()   
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result: 
[image: Result of code on an image from my cellphone]

Comment: Thank you. The eyes are detected, but the png image is still not shown.

Comment: I have just added the results of the algorithm + modified the code to help detect missing files and eye detection failure.

Comment: Thanks a million. It didn't work at first with my image. I tried with another and it worked!